# Is it possible to enter the UK with a child on an Accompanied visa and then leave alone?

Tags: visas, uk, children

I was supposed to leave for Scotland with a group of children for a course tonight, but upon reaching the airport I was told that my visa was an Accompanied Child visa, and I could not travel without my parents. I am fifteen years old.

**Is it legal for me to fly into the UK with a parent, and then have the parent fly back, leaving me there? Will I have any trouble coming back to India?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that when you applied for the visa, you specifically mentioned that you will be traveling with an adult whose name has to be specifically mentioned on your visa. The Gov.UK website clearly mentions that in case this adult is not with you, your entry will be denied.

> When traveling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18)
>   you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and you’ll be refused entry to
>   the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.

Now, assuming your current case, the option which you suggested *should* work in theory. Albeit I won't say it is a safe option **at all**. Ideally, once you get to the UK, unless you break any laws there, you shouldn't be stopped while getting back to India.

On the other hand the correct way to do this is to change your visa into one which allows you to travel alone. Now, I'm not sure how this works in practice, but the Gov.UK site has a [great section](https://www.gov.uk/child-visit-visa/travelling-alone) on traveling alone as on a Child Visitor Visa.

As per this section it should be possible for you to travel alone as long as,

> Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:
>
> - written consent for you to travel to the UK
> - full contact details

and,

> They’ll also need to provide proof that you have somewhere suitable to
>   live during your stay in the UK, including:
>
> - the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying with
> - an address where you will be living
> - details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after you
> - consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the UK

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead now.