# Can a child enter the UK on an accompanied visa and then leave the country alone?

Tags: visas, uk, minors

My daughter who is just under 18 has a child accompanied visa to the UK. I am traveling with her to the UK for a few days. We return from UK on the same day except that she returns to India and I am heading to San Francisco an hour later on the same day.

Is that okay or will we have an issue at immigration into the United Kingdom?

Comment: Why does it matter? Does Britain have exit controls where they verify the ages of passengers departing? As long as the Airline that you've booked tickets on allows your kid to board unaccompanied.

Comment: @nikhil, it's not a question of verifying age. The visa has a written endorsement on it that specifies it is only valid if the holder is accompanied by a named adult.  UKVI is very serious about compliance. They may or may not let her fly depending if someone is there to receive her in India, but the adult will definitely be flagged as entering breach. That will be problematic going forward.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51015/transiting-from-the-us-through-the-uk-on-a-child-visitor-visa/55913#55913

Comment: Hi Gayot, thanks for the immediate response. Isn't the Visa stamped with accompanying adult's name so that while in UK, the minor has someone along with her? In this case, I will be landing with her on the same flight, be with her throughout, and finally go back through immigration with her. After that, she will get on her flight and 1 hour later, I will get on a separate flight to go to SFO.

Comment: @JayashriRamamurti, no you've got it wrong. At the application stage you agreed an undertaking to provide end-to-end supervision of the child. That includes the destination and abandoning the child when you reach Heathrow airside is a breach. However, the UK operates passive exit controls so it wouldn't be discovered until later. But if the carrier spots you haven't bought a ticket (or any other incident like a baggage check) Section 55 kicks in right away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK child visitor visa](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36951/uk-child-visitor-visa)

Comment: Not sure about the duplicate. There's a difference between wanting to travel to the UK entirely unaccomanied and wanting to end the accompaniment as you leave the UK

Comment: Duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31658/drop-off-child-with-accompanied-uk-visa

Comment: I know it's been a very long time ago, but did it work because I'm going through the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Child Visitor Visas have been replaced by the [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) as of 2016 and therefore all visitors are now under the effect of [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) of the [Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules). Specifically, section V4.13 states that:

> A child who holds a visit visa must either:
>
> (a) hold a valid visit visa that states they are accompanied **and will be travelling with an adult identified on that visit visa**; or
>
> (b) hold a visit visa which
> states they are unaccompanied; if neither applies, the child may be
> refused entry unless they meet the requirements of V 4.12.

Therefore it's a violation of the rules to leave the child in the UK after entering the country as it's required that the child is accompanied by the individual named in the visa's endorsement. You agreed to this condition when the visa was issued.

Comment: I'm not sure the last paragraph is correct. The kid would then need a visa of their own, no? (see Q linked by Gayot above.) About the "technically a violation", it would be nice how strict they are about enforcing it. Also there's a comment of Gayot to the Q about section 55, could you refer to that?

Comment: @mts presuming the visa is still valid as of them turning 18, I presume it would become a regular Visitor Visa. We need GayotFow to clarify.

Comment: I seem to remember him saying once that a kid visa remains such a kid visa and either they remain accompanied beyond their 18th birthday or they need a new standard visitor visa (of course I can't find it right now). It actually makes sense to me that a visa does not change category on a birthday. Could you try to reach out to GayotFow in chat?

Comment: @mts yes, there is no such thing as an implicit switch on a visa.  Across the board, including child visitor.  There are corner cases where implicit switching is TOLERATED, but never for child visitor.

Comment: @JonathanReez mts is right, also stop using 'technically', unless you want to define it.

Comment: The question isn't about leaving the child in the UK. The child departs first.

Comment: @DJClayworth: From comments above, it looks like the concern is that putting the child on a plane by herself might be a violation, since from that point until departing UK airspace, the child is no longer "accompanied".

Comment: That sounds like a very strict interpretation. I would at least think it possible that if the parent walks the child to the departure gate, and especially if they arrange for the child to be an unaccompanied minor on the plane, it might be OK. But I don't know that. I'm just looking for something a bit more definitive than the contradictory statement in the last paragraph.

Comment: @mts that's somewhat correct. A friend of mine had a child accompanied visa. After she turned 18, she traveled to the UK alone twice between 2005 and 2008. She was always questioned by the airline but then let go. She did get questioned at immigration once but the officers eventually let her go. I think the UK no longer issues accompanied visas valid beyond the 18th birthday.