# Can my 13 year old sister travel back to her country (India) unaccompanied?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, children

Me and my sister (13 years old), are traveling to the UK and my sister has an accompanied visa. Is it possible for my sister to travel back to her country (India) unaccompanied with airlines escort services, as I wish to stay longer but she can't due to academic reason.

Comment: Also asked here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61387/child-accompanied-visa-returning-alone but no answer posted