# Can I leave UK without the person that is on my visa?

Tags: visas, uk, minors

I’m a minor 17 and I’m from Peru. I have requested a visa for the UK for a short-term study less than 6 months and I didn’t realize that they wrote in there only acc by/ father/. I’ll be entry the country with my father but I will not leave with him. I’ll return alone. If I present at the moment to leave the country a letter consent where both of my parents sign that I’m allowed to leave and entry the country without them. Will they let me leave the UK? Please I’m really worried about it

Comment: Will your father leave the U.K. before you do? Possible duplicate of [Can a child enter the UK on an accompanied visa and then leave the country alone?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61387/can-a-child-enter-the-uk-on-an-accompanied-visa-and-then-leave-the-country-alone)

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately.

Comment: It’s not clear from your question whether you’re already in the UK or not. If you are, IANAL but it seems highly unlikely the UK authorities would prevent you from leaving to go back to Peru, despite having breached the terms of your visa. If you’re not, then you should contact your local Consulate, as per the comment from Michael Hampton